# Compare Datetime values on nvarchar columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In SQL Azure server database, a table has a `nvarchar` column that contains date values in string format (`dd/MM/yyyy`). e.g. `03/11/2011`

Column **ARTICLE1** contains null values for some records.

Below is the query I have tried so far but I'm getting an error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

SQL query

```
select 
    [Code], concat(fname,' ',lname) as Name, [ARTICLE1] 
from 
    #T2 
where    
    CAST(ISNULL( [ARTICLE1], '1900-01-01') AS DATETIME) >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/01/1920', 103) 
    and CAST(ISNULL( [ARTICLE1] , '1900-01-01') AS DATETIME) <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/01/2017', 103) 
    and Category in ('STAFF', 'MANAGER')
```

Comment: Can you please check datetime format of ARTICLE1 column? Is it yyyy-dd-MM or yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: @DMayuri i found the mistake it should be convert instead of cast ..it is dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: Why are you not storing dates in a date column?  It just sets you up for infinite pain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i cant use date column due to table structure, Table structure is Fieldname,FieldValue(can be any thing string,int or date)

Comment: Bad luck.  Horrid table design.  Welcome to a world of pain!

Comment: You can add a statement  ISDATE(ISNULL( [ARTICLE1],0))=1 to filter invalid data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, Need to convert the string to datetime instead of CAST

```
select [Code],concat(fname,' ',lname) as Name,[ARTICLE1] From #T2 where    
 CONVERT( DATETIME, ISNULL( [ARTICLE1] , '1900-01-01'), 103 )  >= CONVERT( DATETIME, '31/01/1920', 103 ) and 
 CONVERT( DATETIME, ISNULL( [ARTICLE1] , '1900-01-01'), 103 )  <= CONVERT( DATETIME, '31/01/2017' , 103 ) and Category in ('STAFF','MANAGER')
```